# Selenium code to extract text from project issue description

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to extract issue content from gitee using selenium in Python. But It gives blank when I try to extract the text. Here is the inspect element:

[image]

I want to extract all the text inside the div class git-issue-description markdown body.

But when i try to extract it using the following code, it didnt work:

```
Issue_description = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'git-issue-description markdown-body').text
```

What should i do different to get the content inside this div class? Here is the link to the website that I am trying to extract text from - https://gitee.com/openharmony/arkui_ace_engine/issues/I92R3M?from=project-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `By.CSS_SELECTOR` with `"div.git-issue-description.markdown-body"` as the selector:

```py
print(driver.find_element("css selector", "div.git-issue-description.markdown-body").text)
```

---

Here's a full [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) script for that:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver()
driver.get("https://gitee.com/openharmony/arkui_ace_engine/issues/I92R3M?from=project-issue")
print(driver.find_element("css selector", "div.git-issue-description.markdown-body").text)
driver.quit()
```

---

Note that `By.CLASS_NAME` can only include a single class name segment, with no spaces allowed. (Yours was `'git-issue-description markdown-body'`, which has 2 class names / contains a space.)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```py
Issue_description = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'git-issue-description.markdown-body').text
```

Selenium changes the `By.CLASS_NAME` selector to `By.CSS_SELECTOR` by adding a dot to the class name. This makes it so that you can only use one class in the method. By adding a dot between the two classes, the CSS selector will look for an element with both classes.

If you want cleaner code you can change the selector to:

```py
issue_description = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.git-issue-description.markdown-body')
text_content = issue_description.text # Take only the text
html_content = issue_description.get_attribute('innerHTML') # Take all the HTML
```